# Calling function second time affects variable from first invocation

Tags: javascript

I was just experimenting and this got me confused. I don't see why calling `foo` two times should affect output of the timeout callback from previous invocation. This code:

```js
let state = {
    age: 0
};
let getState = () => {
     let setState = () => {
        state = {
            age: state.age + 1
        }
    }
    return {
        state,
        setState
    }
}

function foo() {
    let {
        state:st,
        setState
    } = getState();
    replicaUseEffect = () => {
        console.log("replicaUseEffect", st);
    }
    console.log("before", st);

    setState()
    console.log("after", st);


    setTimeout(() => replicaUseEffect(), 1000)
};
foo();
```

produces following output which I am ok with more or less:

```
"before", {
  age: 0
}
"after", {
  age: 0
}
"replicaUseEffect", {
  age: 0
}
```

---

Now, simply call foo twice instead:

```
foo();
foo();
```

And output is this:

```
"before", {
  age: 0
}
"after", {
  age: 0
}
"before", {
  age: 1
}
"after", {
  age: 1
}
"replicaUseEffect", {
  age: 1
}
"replicaUseEffect", {
  age: 1
}
```

Why calling `foo` two times affect **both** `replicaUseEffect` values in the second example and output 1 two times?
I tried also printing inside the `console.log` with `JSON.stringify` but result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that both `replicaUseEffect` calls output the same value, is that `replicaUseEffect` has been defined as a global variable, and so the second call of `foo` **replaces** the previous version of `replicaUseEffect` with a new one. And although its code is exactly the same, it lives in a different closure, which has the `st` local variable of the second execution context of `foo`.

You don't have this effect when `replicaUseEffect` is defined as a local variable:

```js
let state = {
    age: 0
};
let getState = () => {
     let setState = () => {
        state = {
            age: state.age + 1
        }
    }
    return {
        state,
        setState
    }
}

function foo() {
    let {
        state:st,
        setState
    } = getState();
    const replicaUseEffect = () => {
        console.log("replicaUseEffect", st);
    }
    console.log("before", st);

    setState()
    console.log("after", st);


    setTimeout(() => replicaUseEffect(), 1000)
};
foo();
foo();
```